# What does "full connection table" mean in Yan LeCuns comment on 1x1 convolutions?

Tags: convolution, convolutional-neural-network

What does "full connection table" mean in [Yan LeCuns comment on 1x1 convolutions](https://www.facebook.com/yann.lecun/posts/10152820758292143)?

> In Convolutional Nets, there is no such thing as "fully-connected layers". There are only convolution layers with 1x1 convolution
>   kernels and a full connection table.
>
> It's a too-rarely-understood fact that ConvNets don't need to have a fixed-size input. You can train them on inputs that happen to
>   produce a single output vector (with no spatial extent), and then
>   apply them to larger images. Instead of a single output vector, you
>   then get a spatial map of output vectors. Each vector sees input
>   windows at different locations on the input. In that scenario, the
>   "fully connected layers" really act as 1x1 convolutions.

Comment: Does this help: https://sebastianraschka.com/faq/docs/fc-to-conv.html ? If so, great.  If not, I can try to fill in the details.

Comment: @bogovicj Thanks for your fast comment and sorry for such a tardy reply. The link was great and I wish you would have time to explain it more.

Comment: Not a problem. Any questions in particular?  Or would a general overview be worth it?

Comment: In specific,  the way we can feed a non-fixed size input to the ConvNets.